# Puppet: deploy file unless it exists

Tags: puppet

I am having trouble with redis sentinel's config file.  The app updates the config with slave and master data while it is running but every time the puppet agent runs, the file gets reset to the default.

Is there a way to have puppet agent not reset the file?  Something like if the file exists leave it alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ["replace" parameter](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/stable/type.html#file-attribute-replace) of the file resource lets you control whether to manage the content of a file if it already exists.  The default value is true.

Change your file resource to set `replace => false` and if the file exists, the content won't be changed.  Other properties of the file resource (such as owner, mode) will still be managed if specified.